# Activity for different paid the application

Tags: android

I would like to implement an activity with 3 button.
The first is for use the application for 0.99$ 
The second is for use the application with the default data for 4.99$
and the last button is for the buy the full application.

how can implement this? there are some examples like this?

thx

Comment: I think you are looking for help with "in app purchases".  Which is something you'll really have to contact Google about.  Writing the app to behave that way is only part of it.  Actually implementing that billing scheme is something else altogether.

Comment: sorry for my bed explanation question..is possible to remove it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google has a really handy tutorials for this:

An overview of Google's billing setup:
https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/index.html?hl=az

Actually implementing it:
http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html